# A little help to understand Class hierarchy of Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

A little help to understand the python classes and subclasses.
Also which is the parent class for BaseException in python.

Comment: Have you read the documentation or manual, or try something on google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `BaseException.__bases__` to get the parent(s). `__bases__` attribute will give you a tuple of all the parent classes, in this case the parent is `object`. And read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__).